# Parity and Geth node as peers

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, parity, peers, genesis

I'm running an ethereum (with geth) and a parity instance on 2 nodes, using similar genesis files for both. I've also specified the geth node's enode ID as bootnode for parity. Yet the 2 nodes are unable to detect each other.

geth.genesis:

```
{
"nonce": "0x0000000000000042",
"difficulty": "0x4",
"alloc": {
    "6a5b342ec71def8aac337b82969d9ddd811023c9": {
        "balance": "5000000000000000000000000"
    }
},
"mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"timestamp": "0x00",
"parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"extraData": "0x1100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"gasLimit": "0xFFFF0000"
}
```

parity.genesis:

```
{
"name": "node",
"engine": {
      "Ethash": {
              "params": {
                      "gasLimitBoundDivisor": "0x0400",
                      "minimumDifficulty": "0x4",
                      "difficultyBoundDivisor": "0x0800",
                      "durationLimit": "0x0a",
                      "blockReward": "0x4563918244F40000",
                      "registrar": "",
                      "frontierCompatibilityModeLimit": "0x0"
              }
      }
},
"params": {
      "accountStartNonce": "0x0000000000000042",
      "maximumExtraDataSize": "0x20",
      "minGasLimit": "0xFFFF0000",
      "networkID" : "0x16"
},
"genesis": {
      "seal": {
              "ethereum": {
                      "nonce": "0x0000000000000042",
                      "mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
              }
      },
      "difficulty": "0x4",
      "author": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      "timestamp": "0x00",
      "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      "extraData": "0x1100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      "gasLimit": "0xFFFF0000"
},
"nodes": [
],
"accounts": {
      "6a5b342ec71def8aac337b82969d9ddd811023c9": { "balance": "5000000000000000000000000" }
```

Does anyone have an idea about what might be going wrong? I even tried the route of copying parity.genesis to geth.genesis but to no avail. I'm successfully able to connect 2 geth nodes or 2 parity nodes to each-other however.

Comment: If you add the nodes to each other client, what's the log output?

Comment: Surprisingly, manually adding the parity node with admin.addPeer() in geth cli works! What can be the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: The parity peer however disconnected once I started  mining for blocks in geth, with the following log `2017-01-09 21:17:45  Stage 1 block verification failed for 6fd5…b968: Block(InvalidGasLimit(OutOfBounds { min: Some(4294901760), max: None, found: 4290707521 }))`. In fact, the block gas limit declined from 4294901760 in block 0 to 4290707521 in block 1. What can be the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Are you defining the target gas limit when running geth?

Comment: No, I'm defining no others parameters apart from those in the genesis files shown above.

Comment: I removed `minGasLimit` parameter from parity.genesis. Next I get is `Stage 3 block verification failed for #1 (2441…723b)
Error: Block(InvalidDifficulty(Mismatch { expected: 4, found: 131072 }))`. On examining the blocks, I saw block 0 started with difficulty 4, and then block 1 had a difficulty value of 131072.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connection will drop if they are on different chains, you can run Parity with `-lsync=trace` to see what is going on.

It probably has to do with hard fork transitions, Geth does not include them by default. Have a look [here](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/wiki/Chain-specification#coming-from-geth) and try using the [linked generator](https://github.com/keorn/parity-spec).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had manually converted the file to parity format, being unaware of this tool. If possible, it would be helpful to have an online version of it, just like [Parity Config Generator](https://ethcore.github.io/parity-config-generator/), as it requires quite a lot of things to be installed for one time use.